# Counting recurrences of combinations in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, count, aggregate-functions

I have a list of items (e.g. shirts, tops, pants, adidas, nike, puma, lipstick, facewash etc.) and I have categorized them as (shirts, top, pant = clothes, nike, adidas, puma = shoes, lipstick etc. = makeup) and years in a format like this 2017-01-01. I want to find out how many times there were two types of purchases on the same date, for example if I bought makeup and clothes on 2018-02-01 then I want to count that as 1 for a category 'makeup + clothes', if I bought shoes and makeup on 2017-09-06 then I want to count that as 1 for a category 'shoes + makeup'

How can I do this?

I have the following table called Items:

```
Year | Purchases | 
------------------
2017-02-01 | makeup
2018-10-01 | shoes
2019-03-01 | makeup
2017-11-01 | shoes
2017-02-01 | clothing
2016-01-01 | shoes
2018-10-01 | clothing
2017-11-01 | clothing
2019-01-01 | makeup
2016-01-01 | makeup
```

The desired output is something like this:

```
Year | Purchases        | Count
-----------------------
2016 | Shoes + makeup   |  1
2017 | Makeup +clothing |  1
2017 | shoes + Clothing |  2
2018 | Shoes + clothing |  1
...
```

Comment: Please tag the database name on your question. The SQL functions are highly vendor specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach using a self-join and aggregation:

```
select extract(year from t1.date) yr, t1.purchases purchases_1, t2.purchases purchases_2, count(*) cnt
from mytable t1
inner join mytable t2 on t2.date = t1.date and t2.purchases < t1.purchases
group by extract(year from t1.date), t1.purchases, t2.purchases
```

For each year, this counts how many times two products appeared on the same date.

Notes:

- it is counter-intuitive that a column that stores a date should be called `year`; I renamed it to `date` in the query
- you did not tell which database you are running; this uses standard function `extract()` to get the year of each date - not all databases support this function, but they all have alternatives
- the query puts the items in two separate columns - you can concatenate them in the same column of you like